# C++ Check how many times there are numbers in the resulting array

Tags: c++

I'am beginner in C++
Somebody could help me with it.
INT array.Random.
fill an array of 1000 integers with random numbers from 10 to 77. 
Check how many times in the resulting array there are numbers 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60 , 70.
Print the received statistics.

I see it like this but i dont know how make count of numbers in array.

```
int main()
{
    int number[1000];
    int countUnits[7];
    int count = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        number[i] = rand() % 68 + 10;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        if (number[i] % 10 == 0) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Explore the [std::count_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) function and couple it with a lambda predicate.

Comment: @Ron Can you use this? It looks like it returns a single/total count. But, OP seems to need separate counts (i.e. histogram) because of description and his `int countUnits[7];`

Comment: Think out loud:  Assume you know that the number you're looking at currently is 40 (forget how you know this, you figured it out and you know it is 40). Which slot in the `countUnits` array is reserved for adding the number of 40's found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the same way as if you were counting only one number, except you have seven checks and seven counters:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if (number[i] == 10)
        countUnits[0] += 1;
    else if (number[i] == 20)
        countUnits[1] += 1;
    else if ...
...
}
```

Then you notice that there is a pattern to the testing and indexing, and simplify:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if (number[i] % 10 == 0)
        countUnits[number[i]/10-1] += 1;
}
```

Or, if you want to confuse people with your m4d sk1llz:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    countUnits[number[i]/10-1] += number[i] % 10 == 0;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. If `i` was 934, then the count bucket index would be 92. See my answer below

Comment: @CraigEstey Yeah, I had a bug.

Comment: I finished this little program. Thank you very much for helping. i got more experience in this.

Answer (score 0):

You are not far. But you should first initialize `countUnits`:

```
int countUnits[7] = {0};    // enough to zero initialize the whole array
```

You can then count:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    if (number[i] % 10 == 0) {
        countUnits[number[i] / 10 - 1] += 1;
    }
}
```

That way you scan the array only once.

Comment: This is wrong. If `i` was 934, then the count bucket index would be 92. See my answer below

Comment: @CraigEstey: My bad. Thanks to MichalH for fixing the typo.

Answer (score 0):

The index for `countUnits` must be based on the value of `number[i]`.

And *not* `i` as others have suggested. With that (e.g.) if index `i` was 934 and that was evenly divisible by 10, the resultant index would be 92

Here's the code (please forgive the `printf`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int number[1000];
    int countUnits[7] = { 0 };

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        number[i] = rand() % 68 + 10;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        int value = number[i];
        if (value % 10 == 0)
            countUnits[value / 10 - 1] += 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        printf("%d: %d\n",(i + 1) * 10,countUnits[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is C++, it's supposed to be way, way easier. It will read more like Python than like C. That's a good thing in this case!

Here's how I'd write it:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(10, 77);

    std::array<int, 1000> numbers;
    for (auto &number : numbers)
        number = distrib(gen);

    std::map<int, int> counts;
    for (auto const &number : numbers)
        if ((number % 10) == 0)
            counts[number] ++;

    for (auto const &number_count : counts)
    {
        auto number = number_count.first;
        auto count = number_count.second;
        std::cout << number << " found " << count
            << (count == 1 ? " time" : " times") << '\n';
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
10 found 13 times
20 found 15 times
30 found 13 times
40 found 7 times
50 found 15 times
60 found 9 times
70 found 17 times
```